# flutter ternary operator with multiple statements to run

Tags: flutter, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I dont want to put more conditions in ternary operator, rather run 2 statements after evaluating a single condition.

if-else structure would be:

```
    if( maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor ) {
// i want to run both these lines in ternary operator
      **maleCardColor = activeCardColor;
      femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;**

        } else {
          maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
    }
```

i want to use it like:_

```
  maleCardColor = (maleCardColor==inactiveCardColor)?   (maleCardColor = activeCardColor   &&   femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor) : maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor ,
```

Comment: Please add some more code so that we can at least know where within you widget tree are you trying to implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge, if you want to use multi-line in the ternary operator, you can make two methods as mentioned below.

```
  ("A" == "B") ? ternaryTrueMethod() : ternaryFalseMethod();

  void ternaryTrueMethod() {
    /*
    multi-line code here
     */
    return;
  }

  void ternaryFalseMethod() {
    /*
    multi-line code here
     */
    return;
  }
```

The first method is for ternary satisfied & the other one is for ternary unsatisfied.

Comment: wow. Mind blown. 
such a simple solution. yet, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @SaadMansoor I'm glad you liked it. Thank you so much for the upvote and for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `run` top-level function and use it to execute multiple statements:

```
void run(Function() fun) => fun();
```

It would look like this with the ternary operator:

```
maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor
    ? run(() {
        maleCardColor = activeCardColor;
        femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      })
    : maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
```

I believe this is similar to a `Kotlin` function with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could write this, but I would say it has poor readability and a bad style in my opinion.

```
maleCardColor = (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor && (femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor) == inactiveCardColor) ? maleCardColor = activeCardColor : maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
```

The reason this works is because in dart an assignment also returns the value it assigns, so you are doing the assignment as part of the condition for the ternary and simply compare it to the thing you are assigning to. It won't execute if the first part of the condition is already false because it won't even look past the `&&` if the condition before it is already false

Answer (score 0):

```
x =   maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor
    ? {
maleCardColor = activeCardColor,
femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor,
      }
    : maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.